# How to convert from double[] to char[] in c++

Tags: c++

I need to convert array of double to char[] separated with ' '. I'm beginner in c++. Can you, please, tell me how can I do this converting. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at `sprintf` function or `std::stringstream`

Comment: Do you mean type casting or convert double to text string?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly are you having problems with? Converting a double to string? Finding the right algorithm from the standard library? C++? Locales?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/).

This class builds a C++ stream around a `std::string`.

```
std::stringstream s;
s << 1.4 << " " << 1.5 << " " << -5.7;
const char* myS = s.str().c_str();

// Do something with myS.
```

Be careful with memory management. Memory pointed by `myS` shall not been accessed when `s` goes out of scope.

Comment: I thought about that but OP needs char[], not const char[]

Comment: I'm not convinced the OP is quite sure what he or she needs! This is probably what they're looking for.

Comment: Sorry for using your initial answer as a pattern for my answers. This is kind of a protest and/or demonstration against unspecific questions.

Comment: Don't you mean `s.str().c_str()`?

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its as easy as that to convert a double to a string.
But here's a way using C++ stringstreams:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::string to_string(double x);

int main()
{
  double pi = 3.14159;
  std::string str = to_string(pi);

  std::cout << str << std::endl;

  // Cstring:
  char digits[10];
  std::strcpy( digits, str.c_str() );

  std::cout << std::endl << "c-string:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << digits[2] << std::endl;
  std::cout << digits << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

std::string to_string(double x)
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << x;
  return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Note that as of C++11 the standard library has a `to_string` function, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/?kw=transform).

This algorithm lets you iterate over a C++ container and apply a functor over the elements, letting you convert some `container<T>` to `container<U>`.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to show what can happen if the question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::locale`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/locale/?kw=locale).

This lets you modify the format of the stringified version to some region or community specific format.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to show what can happen if the question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [standard containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) instead of raw arrays.

This lets you forget about almost all memory management issues in case of runtime-determined input- and output-sizes.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to show what can happen if the question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/?kw=to_string).

This lets you convert a number to a `std::string`.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to show what can happen if the question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [g++](http://gcc.gnu.org).

This is a free and open source C++ compiler.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to show what can happen if the question is not specific enough.